# How to save/restore view states when activity is destroyed android?

Tags: android, android-activity, io, spinner

what is the best way to restore spinner states, text entered in textViews etc. when an activity is destroyed and reopened?

edit:
here is some of my code how do I make whatever text was entered in writeText be there when onCreate is called again?

```
SharedPreferences sh_Pref;
SharedPreferences.Editor toEdit;

    @Override
public void onDestroy() {
    sharedPrefernces();
    super.onDestroy();
}

    public void sharedPrefernces() {

    sh_Pref = getSharedPreferences("SavedConfig", MODE_PRIVATE);
    toEdit = sh_Pref.edit();
    toEdit.putString("Text", writeText.getText().toString());
    toEdit.commit();

}
```

Comment: save the states in SharedPreferences and then fetch them in onCreate of your activtity when it is restarted

Comment: ok im new to android how do i fetch the SharedPreferences in OnCreate?

Comment: Please see edit above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried out many things but this one is the best approach i found out and used several times.Shows clear thing with example,explained well beautifully in [this](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/best-approach-to-keep-android-fragment-state/en) Post

```
public class MainFragment extends StatedFragment {

...

/**
 * Save Fragment's State here
 */
@Override
protected void onSaveState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveState(outState);
    // For example:
    //outState.putString("text", tvSample.getText().toString());
}

/**
 * Restore Fragment's State here
 */
@Override
protected void onRestoreState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreState(savedInstanceState);
    // For example:
    //tvSample.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("text"));
}

...

}
```

Also provides fragment template for better understanding

```
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
   import android.view.LayoutInflater;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.ViewGroup;

   import com.inthecheesefactory.thecheeselibrary.R;

   /**
   * Created by nuuneoi on 11/16/2014.
   */
public class StatedFragment extends Fragment {

Bundle savedState;

public StatedFragment() {
    super();
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    // Restore State Here
    if (!restoreStateFromArguments()) {
        // First Time, Initialize something here
        onFirstTimeLaunched();
    }
}

protected void onFirstTimeLaunched() {

}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    // Save State Here
    saveStateToArguments();
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    // Save State Here
    saveStateToArguments();
}

////////////////////
// Don't Touch !!
////////////////////

private void saveStateToArguments() {
    if (getView() != null)
        savedState = saveState();
    if (savedState != null) {
        Bundle b = getArguments();
        b.putBundle("internalSavedViewState8954201239547", savedState);
    }
}

////////////////////
// Don't Touch !!
////////////////////

private boolean restoreStateFromArguments() {
    Bundle b = getArguments();
    savedState = b.getBundle("internalSavedViewState8954201239547");
    if (savedState != null) {
        restoreState();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/////////////////////////////////
// Restore Instance State Here
/////////////////////////////////

private void restoreState() {
    if (savedState != null) {
        // For Example
        //tv1.setText(savedState.getString("text"));
        onRestoreState(savedState);
    }
}

protected void onRestoreState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

}

//////////////////////////////
// Save Instance State Here
//////////////////////////////

private Bundle saveState() {
    Bundle state = new Bundle();
    // For Example
    //state.putString("text", tv1.getText().toString());
    onSaveState(state);
    return state;
}

protected void onSaveState(Bundle outState) {

}
}
```

Comment: Thanks but my app is using activities not fragments

Comment: No issues,you can use this with activities too

Comment: onSavedInstanceState() is  not called when an activity is destroyed, only when its paused

Answer (score 1):

If you set an  unique identifier to your textView, acivity will automatically save state of that element. For other purposes, you should overwrite `onSavedInstanceState()` method

Comment: onSavedInstanceState() method is not called when activity is destroyed